# Add middle point handles on selection bounding rectangle for a selected shape

Tags: javascript, paperjs

When a shape is selected in paperjs, for example with this code:

```
var p = new Shape.Circle(new Point(200, 200), 100)
p.strokeColor = 'black';
p.bounds.selected = true;
```

the result is a bounding rectangle with [handles on edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpVw9.png).

How can I easily add handles on the middle of bounding rectangle sides as in picture [bounding rectangle with middle handles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNewB.png)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The midpoints of each side of the *bounding rectangle* of your `Path` are already stored in:

- `p.bounds.topCenter`
- `p.bounds.bottomCenter`
- `p.bounds.leftCenter`
- `p.bounds.rightCenter`

Hence making it fairly straightforward to create shapes on those points:

```
var p = new Shape.Circle(new Point(200, 200), 100)
p.strokeColor = 'black';
p.bounds.selected = true;

[
  p.bounds.topCenter,
  p.bounds.bottomCenter,
  p.bounds.leftCenter,
  p.bounds.rightCenter
].forEach(function(midpoint) {
  var handle = new Path.Rectangle(new Rectangle(midpoint.subtract(5), 10));
  handle.fillColor = '#1A9FE9';
})
```

Here's a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/bVBBasMwEPyKUA+xwYik0EMSeigmPYfmGOcgy+tIWN418ro9hPy9UuqmFHJZ2JmdYWcuEnUPciMPHbCxspCGmrR/6iAG8SoQvsTB6gFU6YLxkCVgTw45e14uCxFHXohVnBUOauRAHZTkKUTtovbadIttYmqasBnVCB4MQxNZDhNEqsJjhULcL5iGEpAhFP/gmpipf8R4aPkRHtzZzkSFJ9VS2Gljs3ZCw44w610zpBy5uCRdCmw1Nh7m1HvNVn3EbzWe59x/269YjVPNQRvOXm415Pk2mf0YqdZ5fy/jafW2ft+tUx3XPBZdB9DdzWSUm+Pp+g0=) of the code.

You can't alter the default selection bounding rectangle that Paper.js draws when you do: `item.selected = true`. You'll have to draw them yourself every time you want to select something.

What I usually do in such situations is to write a function to select the shapes for me; that function would also draw my custom bounding rectangle.

For example:

```
var p = new Shape.Circle(new Point(200, 200), 100)
p.strokeColor = 'black';

function selectItem(item) {
  item.selected = true;

  [
    item.bounds.topCenter,
    item.bounds.bottomCenter,
    item.bounds.leftCenter,
    item.bounds.rightCenter
  ].forEach(function(midpoint) {
    var handle = new Path.Rectangle(new Rectangle(midpoint.subtract(5), 10));
    handle.fillColor = '#1A9FE9';
  })
}

selectItem(p)
```